# how I can create numpy matrix of specified numbers

Tags: python, numpy

how I can create matrix using python numpy such this

```
array([[ 0.01,  0.02,  0.03,  0.04,  0.05,  0.06,  0.07,  0.08,  0.09,  0.1 ],
   [ 0.11,  0.12,  0.13,  0.14,  0.15,  0.16,  0.17,  0.18,  0.19,  0.2 ],
   [ 0.21,  0.22,  0.23,  0.24,  0.25,  0.26,  0.27,  0.28,  0.29,  0.3 ],
   [ 0.31,  0.32,  0.33,  0.34,  0.35,  0.36,  0.37,  0.38,  0.39,  0.4 ],
   [ 0.41,  0.42,  0.43,  0.44,  0.45,  0.46,  0.47,  0.48,  0.49,  0.5 ],
   [ 0.51,  0.52,  0.53,  0.54,  0.55,  0.56,  0.57,  0.58,  0.59,  0.6 ],
   [ 0.61,  0.62,  0.63,  0.64,  0.65,  0.66,  0.67,  0.68,  0.69,  0.7 ],
   [ 0.71,  0.72,  0.73,  0.74,  0.75,  0.76,  0.77,  0.78,  0.79,  0.8 ],
   [ 0.81,  0.82,  0.83,  0.84,  0.85,  0.86,  0.87,  0.88,  0.89,  0.9 ],
   [ 0.91,  0.92,  0.93,  0.94,  0.95,  0.96,  0.97,  0.98,  0.99,  1.  ]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
np.linspace(0.01, 1, 100).reshape(10, 10)
```

output:

```
array([[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1 ],
       [0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2 ],
       [0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.3 ],
       [0.31, 0.32, 0.33, 0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.4 ],
       [0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.5 ],
       [0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59, 0.6 ],
       [0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.66, 0.67, 0.68, 0.69, 0.7 ],
       [0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8 ],
       [0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87, 0.88, 0.89, 0.9 ],
       [0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1.  ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

np.array([[(i+j)/100 for i in range(1, 11)] for j in range(0, 100, 10)])
```